# XSLT Document() function result contains unwanted xmlns=""

Tags: xml, xslt

XSLT gurus,

I have an XSLT that is including an unwanted **xmlns=""** in the output. I've seen this problem/question asked and answered on this site many times, but I can't seem to get any of the answers to work for what I'm doing. And I have to warn you that I am new to XSLT and not very good at it.

My XSLT collects a set of data from the application that calls it, and then also uses document() to pick up additional data. This all works fine, I just need to get rid of the **xmlns=""**

the XML called by document() is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><BiExport xmlns="">
<ExportData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Phone>8885551212</Phone>
<ClientRefCmtSuffix/>
<UDFData>
<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">MyCompany Completed Date</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">06/24/2013</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>
<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Rush</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">0</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>
<DictionaryEntry>
<Key xsi:type="xsd:string">Suffix</Key>
<Value xsi:type="xsd:string">0000000000</Value>
</DictionaryEntry>
</UDFData>
<ReportCreateDate>2014-09-26T15:45:48.83952-07:00</ReportCreateDate>
</ExportData>
</BiExport>
```

And yes, I know it has `<BiExport xmlns="">`, no I can't change that, and even when I removed it before applying my XSLT it didn't make any difference.

My XSLT is

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:bean="http://www.MyCompany.com/eventgenerator/beans">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" />

  <xsl:variable name="ReportCreateDate" select="bean:FileEvent/bean:Context[@Id='XPathStep']/bean:Item[@Name='ReportCreateDate']/@Value"/>
  <xsl:variable name="PDFFile" select="concat($PDFFilename, '.', $PDFFileExt)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="InputFile" select="bean:FileEvent/bean:Context[@Id='XPathStep']/bean:Item[@Name='InputFile']/@Value"/>
  <xsl:variable name="PDFFilename" select="bean:FileEvent/bean:Context[@Id='XSLTStep']/bean:Item[@Name='PDFFilename']/@Value"/>
  <xsl:variable name="InputFilePath" select="bean:FileEvent/bean:Context[@Id='ArchiveMessageStep']/bean:Item[@Name='ArchiveDirectory']/@Value"/>
  <xsl:variable name="InputFileString" select="concat($InputFilePath, '\', $PDFFilename, '.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template name="UDFs" match="document($InputFileString)/BiExport/ExportData/UDFData/DictionaryEntry">
    <xsl:param name="pKey" select="." />
    <Item name="{$pKey}">
      <xsl:value-of select="../Value"/>
    </Item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <MDXPackage version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.MyCompany.com/schemas">
      <Payload>
        <PayloadContext>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="document($InputFileString)/BiExport/ExportData/UDFData/DictionaryEntry/Key" />

          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string($ReportCreateDate)">
              <Item name="ReportCreateDate">
                <xsl:value-of select="$ReportCreateDate"/>
              </Item>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>

          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string($PDFFile)">
              <Item name="PDFFile">
                <xsl:value-of select="$PDFFile"/>
              </Item>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
          <!-- more of the same follows-->

        </PayloadContext>
      </Payload>
    </MDXPackage>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output is

```
<MDXPackage xmlns="http://www.mitchell.com/schemas" version="1.0">
<Payload>
<PayloadContext>
<Item xmlns="" name="MyCompany Completed Date">06/24/2013</Item>
<Item xmlns="" name="Rush">0</Item>
<Item xmlns="" name="Suffix">0000000000</Item>
<Item name="ReportCreateDate">2014-09-26T13:53:28.3831684-07:00</Item>
<Item name="ClaimantPhone">8885551212</Item>
</PayloadContext>
</Payload>
</MDXPackage>
```

Thanks in advance for any help in understanding why I get the empty namespace declaration and how to get rid of it.

DL

Comment: What's in your input document (the XML document you are applying the transformation to)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This all works fine, I just need to get rid of the xmlns=""

This is not a matter of getting rid of the xmlns="". They are there for a good reason.The reason is that the parent elements `MDXPackage`, `Payload` and `PayloadContext` are all in a namespace (`"http://www.mitchell.com/schemas"`) and the `Item`s are not.

If you want to remove the no-namespace bindings, you must place the Items in the same namespace as their ancestors. It **probably** means changing this:

```
  <Item name="{$pKey}">
    <xsl:value-of select="../Value"/>
   </Item>
```

to:

```
<Item xmlns="http://www.MyCompany.com/schemas" name="{$pKey}">
    <xsl:value-of select="../Value"/>
</Item>
```

Note that this is **not** a cosmetic change; it actually changes the name of the element.

Comment: An alternative way to achieve the same thing would be to move the `xmlns="http://www.MyCompany.com/schemas"` from the `MDXPackage` inside the template up onto the top-level `xsl:stylesheet`. This would have the effect of putting all unprefixed literal elements in the stylesheet into that namespace.

Comment: +1 I tried this and it also worked. Thanks to both Ian and @michael.